# ajax error handling works not as expected with CORS

Tags: ajax, cors

I've got another issue with CORS. I made a setup for ajax to handle some errors but the problem is now some are never triggered with cross domain requests.

I know it is not possible to catch preflights (timeouts) because they are fired by the browser, is it? But I thought it should be possible to catch an internal server error  with the .e.g. GET after. The error handling works without CORS (turns out 500 is converted to 0)

my setup which is never called:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        statusCode: {

            500: function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

                if (data.status === 500) {
                    window.location.hash = "#error";
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

the GET request:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:'GET',
        timeout:1000
    }).done (function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        updateCookie (jqXHR);
        Logger.log("finished loading " + log);
        callback(data);

    }).fail (function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        Logger.log("failure loading " + log);

    });
```

Anybody a hint for me how to get around that problem?
Greetings

**Update:** Ok debugged again and found that the fail is called but instead 0f 500 -> status 0 is returned.

---

the GET request after successful preflight:

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-CSRF-TOKEN: 11258a06-36ea-4a21-a935-d215fcc92714
X-Requested-With: undefined
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

the response from the server as expected when trying to get a resource which was deleted:

```
Connection: close
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 08 Feb 2016 20:33:12 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
statusCode: 500
```

instead of this 500 is in ajax setup status 0 called.

Comment: You want to catch the `GET` request? If you receive a 403 forbidden due to CORS there is no following `GET` request.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The issue is as I wrote in the update that some errors I try to catch are not the same like in the console. 500 is 0 and for example the timeout is never called (this might be an issue of the preflights the browser sends but I think there is no way to catch them). CORS works fine  but I would also like to have a good error handling. Is there anyway to catch the timeouts of preflights? Why is 500 returned as 0 with CORS but not without? Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, I *think* I understand now: your *preflight* request is getting a 500 response. Is that right? If your preflight fails for any reason, then your request fails, and you don't get access to any cross-origin information.

Comment: Not exactly: for example if I request a source which is not present -> preflight goes through but GET returns 500 which would be ok. But i wondered why the error was never thrown. It turns out that the 500 is 0 in ajax status. But 500 is not the only one. Don't know why. Second: if a preflight times out because the server does not response I don't receive a timeout. But I believe it is not possible to catch them because they are sent by the browser, right?

Comment: (#1) If the preflight has gone through, and your GET is issued, then you should be able to see the error response to your GET. The fact that you get see a failed CORS request (after a *successful* preflight!) suggests to me that something is wrong specifically with your GET response (e.g., it's missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or something similar that would cause a non-preflighted CORS request to fail). (#2) It is not possible to learn anything about preflight success/failure from a browser script.

Comment: (1) I only see the failed reponse because I want it :). I just try to make my error handling better. But I'm wondering why a internal server error 500 (developer tools) is a 0 in ajax. (2) So from the answer below I see evertime a timeout (e.g. network error) occurs there is a status 0 thrown. But you are right that is everthing I can get from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS specification states under the [*Cross-Origin Request with Preflight*](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) section:

> The following request rules are to be observed while making the preflight request:
>
> ...
>
> **If the response has an HTTP status code that is not in the 2xx range**
>
> - Apply the network error steps.
>
> **If there is a network error**
>
> - In case of DNS errors, TLS negotiation failure, or other type of network errors, apply the network error steps. Do not request any kind of end user interaction.

Therefore, a preflight that meets a 500 response or experiences a timeout (or any other network failure) triggers the specification's "network error steps." The [network error steps](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#network-error-steps) are the same error steps used whenever there is a general CORS failure (e.g., wrong origin allowed, no CORS headers present at all, etc.):

> Whenever the **network error steps** are applied, terminate the algorithm that invoked this set of steps and set the cross-origin request status to *network error*.

In the browser environment, a "*network error*" status corresponds to the status `0`.

In order to prevent this from happening, the server must ensure that the preflight does not fail. Alternatively, change your request so that it is simple (i.e., uses only simple methods and headers) and therefore does not require a preflight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand, so when the server is not running and the preflight does not go through there is always a 0 status thrown?

Comment: @coffeLord Correct. An offline server would cause a network failure. The client behavior for a preflight that sees a 500 response and a preflight that fails due to an offline server is identical.

Comment: Ok thank you, just one more question or approval. If my preflight goes through and my GET receives 500, it is also status 0? So i have to throw explicit a different error than 500 to differ between them?

Comment: @coffeLord If your preflight goes through, then the actual response status code for the GET will be visible (i.e., you *can* see the 500 response). If you can't see the 500 response, that means that **something went wrong with the CORS in your request**, either in the preflight or the actual request. Since you say that the preflight goes fine, then the server must not be including correct CORS headers for the GET response. The actual response following a successful preflight is treated as a normal CORS request: it still needs `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: I can see the 500 response but in the ajax error handling the 0 status is triggered. That only happens with CORS, without 500 is triggered. That is what I don't understand

Comment: @coffeLord You need to provide a complete example with all requests, responses, and headers. What you're describing simply shouldn't happen, so it's not possible to diagnose your issue without seeing the headers coming and going between the client and server. If both (1) the preflight is successful and (2) the request is successful then the `status` will not be `0`. The actual request would fail (even after a successful preflight) either due to a bad `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`.